# How can I convert multiple completion handlers to async?

Tags: swift, async-await, apple-vision

I am using Apple's Vision framework to run multiple detection requests against one image.

[`VNImageRequestHandler.perform()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagerequesthandler/2880297-perform) schedules multiple requests (likely in a separate thread). Completion handlers are defined for the individual requests. In the end, results should be assigned to a class var.

From my understanding, continuations are the best way to convert completion handler based APIs to async code. However, continuations can only be resumed once.

`AsyncStream` seems like a more viable solution. However, results can arrive in any order and I only have a static number of requests.

What are the most idiomatic async paradigms to use with the following code?

```swift
// non-async code
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(url: url)
let faceQualityRequest = VNDetectFaceCaptureQualityRequest { request, err in
    guard err == nil else { return }
    self.faceDetectionResults = request.results
}
let featurePrintRequest = VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest { request, err in
    guard err == nil else { return }
    self.featurePrintResults = request.results
}
try handler.perform([faceQualityRequest, featurePrintRequest])
```

Comment: I would use an AsyncThrowingStream or a TaskGroup

Comment: Queue , operation Queue and completion handler for queue, you can use from queuer, it's very simple: https://github.com/FabrizioBrancati/Queuer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand why, when seeing a series of closures, one might jump to the idea of asynchronous sequences or task groups, but we should note that [`perform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagerequesthandler/2880297-perform) is synchronous, not asynchronous. So, I might suggest that the relevant question is less “what do I do with these closures”, but rather, “how do I avail myself of a slow, synchronous API within Swift concurrency”.

A few observations:

1. Given that `perform` is a synchronous function, you should be aware that you should avoid blocking the current actor. So, you theoretically could move it into a detached task.

   Having having been said, even that is not prudent. E.g., in WWDC 2022’s [Visualize and optimize Swift concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110350/?time=1186), Apple explicitly advises moving the blocking code out of the Swift concurrency system:

   > Be sure to avoid blocking calls in tasks. … If you have code that needs to do these things, move that code outside of the concurrency thread pool – for example, by running it on a DispatchQueue – and bridge it to the concurrency world using continuations.

   See [async/await: How do I run an async function within a @MainActor class on a background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76665311/1271826)
2. You are focusing on the closures provided to `VNDetectFaceCaptureQualityRequest` and `VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest`. But those closures are an optional convenience and you can instead just use their respective `results` ([here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectfacecapturequalityrequest/3750966-results) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vngenerateimagefeatureprintrequest/3750984-results)).

So, you might end up with something like:

```swift
func faceAndFeature(for url: URL) async throws -> ([VNFaceObservation], [VNFeaturePrintObservation]) {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let faceQualityRequest = VNDetectFaceCaptureQualityRequest()
            let featurePrintRequest = VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest()

            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(url: url)

            do {
                try handler.perform([faceQualityRequest, featurePrintRequest])
                continuation.resume(returning: (faceQualityRequest.results ?? [], featurePrintRequest.results ?? []))
            } catch {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E.g.,

```swift
let (faceQuality, featurePrint) = try await faceAndFeature(for: url)
print("faceQuality =", faceQuality)
print("featurePrint =", featurePrint)
```

---

It should be noted that the above will not return any results until `perform` finishes all the requests. You can, alternatively, create two [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md) instances, one for faces and one for features. E.g.,

```swift
let faceChannel = AsyncThrowingChannel<[VNFaceObservation], Error>()
let featureChannel = AsyncThrowingChannel<[VNFeaturePrintObservation], Error>()

func analyzeImage(at url: URL) async throws {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let faceQualityRequest = VNDetectFaceCaptureQualityRequest { request, error in
                Task { [weak self] in
                    guard let self else { return }

                    guard error == nil, let results = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] else {
                        faceChannel.fail(error ?? VisionError.invalidRequestType)
                        return
                    }

                    await faceChannel.send(results)
                }
            }

            let featurePrintRequest = VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest { request, error in
                let results = request.results
                Task { [weak self, results] in
                    guard let self else { return }

                    guard error == nil, let results = results as? [VNFeaturePrintObservation] else {
                        featureChannel.fail(error ?? VisionError.invalidRequestType)
                        return
                    }

                    await featureChannel.send(results)
                }
            }

            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(url: url)

            do {
                try handler.perform([faceQualityRequest, featurePrintRequest])
                continuation.resume()
            } catch {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then monitor those channels:

```swift
await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
    group.addTask {
        for try await observations in self.faceChannel {
            …
        }
    }

    group.addTask {
        for try await observations in self.featureChannel {
            …
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, start the request:

```swift
try await analyzeImage(at: url)
```

A few notes:

1. The Vision framework does not appear to be audited for `Sendable` yet, so you might want to designate it as `@preconcurrency` to silence annoying warnings about this:

   ```swift
   @preconcurrency import Vision
   ```
2. Note, in SwiftUI you can launch these `for`-`await`-`in` loops from the [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) view modifier and they will be canceled when the view is dismissed. In UIKit/AppKit, you will have to keep your own reference to the `Task` that launched these and manually `cancel` them when the view in question disappears.

Comment: Thanks for this truly helpful and detailed answer. Your post also covers further questions that have been floating in my mind. Impressive!