# Ensuring started tasks have priority over scheduled tasks

Tags: swift, concurrency

I have a Swift actor singleton, called `Processor`, which takes incoming requests to process some value, and when it has finished processing that value, it posts the result somewhere.

The processing of the value is CPU intensive but can be split into separate chunks which can then execute in parallel over a few CPU cores. The `Processor` actor can receive more requests than it can do in parallel, and so those extra requests should wait for the in-progress requests to finish before they begin processing. **This is the problem I'm having: my `Processor` prefers to start processing new values before it has completed processing existing ones.**

The following shows a very basic example. I'm using `sleep()` to simulate a heavy CPU workload. (This example probably doesn't require an `actor` as all its functions are `nonisolated`, but I do make use of the actor in my real code.)

```swift
actor Processor {
    nonisolated func enqueue(value: Int) {
        Task {
            await performProcessing(of: value)
        }
    }
    
    nonisolated private func performProcessing(of value: Int) async {
        async let resultA = performSubProcessing(of: value)
        async let resultB = performSubProcessing(of: value)
        async let resultC = performSubProcessing(of: value)
        
        _ = await (resultA, resultB, resultC)
        
        print("Finished processing", value)
    }
    
    nonisolated private func performSubProcessing(of number: Int) -> Int {
        sleep(1)
        
        return 0
    }
}
```

The dispatching of tasks to the actor might look something like this:

```swift
let processor = Processor()

for i in 0 ..< 1000 {
    processor.enqueue(value: i)
}
```

On a machine with at least three cores (because in this example the task can be split into three separate subtasks), I'd expect to have the `print` statement confirm that the first value enqueued to the `Processor` has finished processing 1 second after it was sent (with more cores, it should process multiple values simultaneously).

Instead, while it performs `performSubProcessing` of the first task immediately, when those are finished, it doesn't continue with the rest of that task's `performProcessing` and instead starts `performSubProcessing` for the next values. It does usually start delivering results before it has performed `performSubProcessing` for all 1000 values, but it's still significantly delayed. Ideally, when all three `performSubProcessing` for a value has finished, it should immediately complete the rest of `performProcessing` before starting with the next enqueued value.

I tried changing the `enqueue` function like so, with the idea that once it starts executing the high priority task, it won't start the low priority tasks until that high priority one is complete, but this didn't seem to have any effect:

```swift
nonisolated func enqueue(value: Int) {
    Task(priority: .low) {
        Task(priority: .high) {
            await performProcessing(of: value)
        }
    }
}
```

The other way of doing this I can think of would be to simply store the requests in a queue and execute them one by one, waiting for one to finish before starting the next one. The problem with this is that with a sufficient amount of cores, multiple requests should be able to be executed in parallel, and I think it's probably better to let the concurrency executor decide how many tasks I can do in parallel, rather than me trying to figure out some value, especially when there are other tasks running elsewhere.

Comment: Re your second comment, I don't want any core to sit idle if there's any work to do. If there are currently fewer tasks than there are cores for the initial batch, and then a new batch comes in, the remaining cores should begin work on that batch. But the first batch should always have priority, even when it encounters suspension points. (It doesn't need to terminate any in-progress tasks of more recently added batches in case the initial batch suddenly spawns a bunch of new subtasks, and perhaps that's the issue, I'll experiment with `Task.yield`.)

Comment: To clarify, processing of a single value should usually only take a fraction of a second, but when a bunch are initially scheduled and they all (undesirably) complete together, waiting for the initial results can take several seconds. The first value's result _should_ be delivered in the same amount of time regardless of how many values are initially scheduled. (But I still want it to start work on the next values if there are cores to spare.)

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line, when you start a series of tasks, there can be races and the Swift concurrency has some discretion as to the order that they will start:

[image]

(That is zoomed in (with a span of 0.3 msec), so you can see the race with respect to when they start. And I have modified it to have four subtasks per batch, running on a six-core device, so I manifest the “out of cores” flow. The last two subtasks for batch 2 are off to the right, not really salient to this conversation.)

Now, if these are truly independent calculations (i.e., no resource contention, not overcommiting the system), the fact that the second batch is running concurrently really should not have too much impact on the performance of the first batch’s tasks. But let us set that aside for a second.

The simple solution is to await the prior task:

```swift
private var previousTask: Task<Void, Error>?

func enqueueAwaitPrior(_ item: Item) {
    previousTask = Task { [previousTask] in
        try await previousTask?.value
        await performProcessing(item)
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

That admittedly may be over-compensating, not starting the second batch until the first batch *finishes.* But it’s a nice, simple approach.

Also, when using [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency), we really want to make sure to add a cancelation handler (so the caller has the discretion to cancel the process should the view in question be dismissed, or what have you). So, we would add cancelation handling:

```swift
func enqueueWithCancellationSupport(_ item: Item) async throws {
    let task = Task { [previousTask] in
        try await previousTask?.value
        await performProcessing(item)
    }

    previousTask = task

    try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        try await task.value
    } onCancel: {
        task.cancel()
    }
}
```

Needless to say, adding cancelation handling presumes that “processing” and “sub-processing” periodically `try Task.checkCancellation()` (i.e., that these routines handle cancelation, too).

As a refinement, we might not want to have two cores sitting idle while waiting for the first batch to finish. So, we might use an [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md) to keep track of the batch processes. E.g., we might create a channel of items to be processed and iterate through those:

```swift
let channel = AsyncChannel<Item>()

func monitor() async throws {
    for await item in channel {
        let task = Task { try await performProcessing(item) }

        try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
            _ = try await task.value
        } onCancel: {
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Then, the “enqueue” method would simply `send` a value to that channel:

```swift
func enqueueWithChannel(_ item: Item) async throws {
    await channel.send(item)
}
```

Now, it will not even attempt to start tasks for the second batch until the tasks for the first batch are all started. Yielding on a six-core device (again, zoomed in so you can see the timing of when these tasks start):

[image]

---

Now, the details will vary greatly based upon your implementation, but the general idea is that you can use `AsyncChannel` to manage the starting of the tasks. A few implementation details to be aware of:

- I would suggest that the async algorithm periodically `try Task.checkCancellation()` to support task cancelation.
- You said:

  > processing of a single value should usually only take a fraction of a second…

  If each task only takes a fraction of a second, the modest, fixed overhead of multithreading may start to have a material negative impact upon the performance gains of parallelism. We usually want to make sure there is enough work on each thread (e.g., striding). E.g., on a six-core device, we will never achieve the theoretical 6× performance gain, but we would like to see something like 5.5×-5.8× gain. But if the amount of work on each thread is very low, e.g., fractions of a second, the performance gain will be far more modest, even slower in worst-case scenarios (even in the absence of contention issues).
- You said:

  > The first value’s result should be delivered in the same amount of time regardless of how many values are initially scheduled. (But I still want it to start work on the next values if there are cores to spare.)

  If the processing time required for the first item is degraded by the starting of additional tasks on other cores, that suggests some contention to some shared resource is taking place. Perhaps some synchronized memory or object. Perhaps you are doing something that requires the GPU. It is impossible to identify the source of the problem on the basis of what has been shared so far.

  But perhaps the above, “wait for the prior item to *finish*” pattern may be sufficient.
- Note that app developers have a “contract” to never impede forward progress of the Swift concurrency system. See [async/await: How do I run an async function within a @MainActor class on a background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76650710/async-await-how-do-i-run-an-async-function-within-a-mainactor-class-on-a-backg/76665311#76665311).

  In this case, one might add a `Task.yield()` in the calculation routine. But with [actor reentrancy](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md#actor-reentrancy), that unfortunately breaks the above logic, which relies upon the constraining of tasks to the number of threads on the cooperative thread pool.

  As discussed in that other Stack Overflow answer, one might be inclined to just move this computationally intensive logic out of the Swift concurrency system entirely, and wrap it in a continuation.
- As is hopefully illustrated by the above, using Instruments’ “Points of Interest” tool is very helpful in visualizing the timing of tasks. See [How to identify key events in Xcode Instruments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017843/how-to-identify-key-events-in-xcode-instruments/39416673#39416673)

  With “intervals”, you can visualize where tasks start and end, the elapsed time, etc. Instruments also has some good Swift concurrency tools (though intervals are my go-to diagnostic tool). Also see WWDC 2022 video [Visualize and optimize Swift concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110350/).