# Change completion for async Task which is "in-progress" (Swift Concurrency)?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, completion, swift-concurrency

I need to handle an asynchronous task result. The problem is if I call it when it is in progress I need to update completion.

In `GCD` it will look somehow like that:

```
func someFunc(completion: (() -> ())?) {
        if isLoading {
            if let completion {
                delayedCompletion = completion
            }
            return
        }
        isLoading = true
        delayedCompletion = completion

        //example of some async task
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.delayedContinuation?()
            self?.delayedContinuation = nil
        }
    }
```

But how to do that with `async/await`? Tried to write code:

```
func someFunc() async {
        if isLoading {
            return await withCheckedContinuation { [weak self] checkedContinuation in
                self?.delayedContinuation = checkedContinuation
            }
        }
        isLoading = true
        return await withCheckedContinuation { [weak self] checkedContinuation in
            self?.delayedContinuation = checkedContinuation
            Task { @MainActor [weak self] in
                self?.delayedContinuation?.resume()
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it correct or are there other ways to add a varying `completion` block?

Comment: I think you should rething whole concept and use some [GlobalActor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/globalactor?language=Swift) to serialize the callbacks (if I properly understood your usage of that `delayed…`

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the global actor suggestion, but you are correct that we really should step back and understand the broader problem. Swift concurrency often employs very different patterns, but it is hard to advise without knowing what the broader question is. (With no offense, the same is true for Gargo’s prior question, where info about the broader problem would have helped inform the answer.) By offering abstract GCD examples with very strange (anti)patterns, it is unnecessarily hard to provide good answers.

Comment: Found in documentation that leaving `CheckingContinuation` with no `resume` call cause leaks. So my code is incorrect. But anyways GCD somehow allows that

Comment: @Rob, yeah, context is required. Gargo, why exactly do you need to switch the callback? What is the broader problem?

Comment: @user28434'mstep It is related to ads. App enters background and enters foreground. In this case I need to load ads. I don't need to reload ad if it is already loading but loading completion may be changed. I hoped I can do it without of completion closures

Comment: Well, for `async` function "callback" is whatever you put after you `await` call that function, so you probably don't need the switching mechanism. And to async load ad once you may just store `Task` with this loading in the property, and then access its [`value`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/value-60t02) (with await ofc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few basic patterns:

1. Await prior task.

   ```swift
   actor AdManager {
       var inProgressTask: Task<Void, Error>? // if you don’t `try` anything inside the `Task {…}`, this property would be `Task<Void, Never>?` 

       func nextAdWithWait() async throws {
           if let inProgressTask {
               try await inProgressTask.value
               return
           }

           let task = Task {
               defer { inProgressTask = nil }

               try await fetchAndPresentAd()
           }
           inProgressTask = task

           // note, because this is unstructured concurrency, we want to manually handle cancelation

           try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
               try await task.value
           } onCancel: {
               task.cancel()
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Cancel prior task and launch a new one.

   ```swift
   func nextAdWithCancelPrevious() async throws {
       inProgressTask?.cancel()

       let task = Task {
           defer { inProgressTask = nil }

           try await fetchAndPresentAd()
       }
       inProgressTask = task

       try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
           try await task.value
       } onCancel: {
           task.cancel()
       }
   }
   ```

---

Having shown a couple of basic patterns, you likely want to fetch ads and present them in the UI, so you want to decouple the fetching from the presentation in the UI.

One might generate an asynchronous sequence of the ads from some “ad manager” and yield values as ads are fetched. So the UI can initiate the “periodically fetch ads” and then process them as they come in.

```swift
actor AdManager {
    /// Generate sequence of ads

    func ads(durationBetweenAds: Duration = .seconds(60)) -> AsyncStream<Ad> {
        AsyncStream { continuation in
            let task = Task {
                defer { continuation.finish() }
                
                while !Task.isCancelled {
                    if let ad = await nextAd() {
                        continuation.yield(ad)
                        try? await Task.sleep(for: durationBetweenAds)
                    } else {
                        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(10)) // in case ad server is down or broken, don't flood it with requests (but, at the same time, maybe not wait a full minute before you try again)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            continuation.onTermination = { _ in
                task.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func nextAd() async -> AdManager.Ad? {…}
}

extension AdManager {
    /// model structure for a given ad … perhaps your ad platform already has a model object for this
    
    struct Ad {…}
}
```

Then the UI can monitor this asynchronous sequence. E.g., in UIKit:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var adsTask: Task<Void, Never>?
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        adsTask = Task { await showAds() }
    }    
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        adsTask?.cancel()
    }
    
    func showAds() async {
        let adManager = await AdManager()
        let ads = await adManager.ads()
        
        for await ad in ads {
            await showAdInUI(ad)
        }
    }

    func showAdInUI(_ ad: AdManager.Ad) async {…}
}
```

In SwiftUI, you don’t need this unstructured concurrency. Just directly `await` the `showAds` function in a [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) view modifier, and it will start it when the view appears and will cancel it automatically when the view disappears. But, in UIKit, we need to manually handle cancelation, like above.

Now, you haven’t shared your ad framework, so many of the details above may vary. But don’t get lost in the details. The basic idea in Swift concurrency is that you likely want an asynchronous sequence of ads, and then let the UI iterate through this sequence and present them as they come in. This is the natural Swift concurrency pattern for consuming an asynchronous sequence of events.

Comment: it is almost exactly one I need. I also thought about an idea that in GCD `DispatchWorkItem` is declared but is not run (until your command), `NSOperation` is the same but `Task` is planned to execute immediately when you declare it. Is it possible to run it later manually?

Comment: @Gargo, just set task property value when you need it to start executing

Comment: @Gargo – There is no direct analog in Swift concurrency. But, I’m begging you: Please stop asking about “what is the direct equivalent of such-and-such GCD object” Swift concurrency is not a GCD API replacement; it is a different way to think about concurrency issues. (E.g., we used async sequences for your ads.) So, in the GCD work item example, if you have a real (not abstract, not theoretical) problem, _x,_ that you would have previously solved with dispatch work items, then ask “how do I do _x_ in Swift concurrency”, not “what is the equivalent to dispatch work items”.

Comment: Hey, don’t get me wrong: You will definitely find cases where a Swift concurrency solution is less elegant than some common legacy pattern (my favorite example is `Operations`’s `maxConcurrentOperationCount`). But, nine times out of ten, when you don’t see some direct analog to some old familiar API, it is because Swift concurrency begs for a completely different (and often, much better) approach. It will take a little time to wrap your head around it, but it is always better ask about the broader problem, not a specific API equivalent.

Comment: Another edge-case example would be “how do I call some slow synchronous API (which I cannot refactor to use Swift concurrency)” to which Apple explicitly suggest that “you can’t, so just use GCD for that, and then wrap that it a Swift concurrency continuation”. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76665311/1271826. But these are edge-cases.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already mentioned, all you need to do is store a reference to the Task you are using which you can then await on multiple lines of code.

However, to guarantee proper access to the Task property, I prefer to store it in a dedicate Actor:

```
/// SingleTaskProxy allows free async calls to a single task.
/// If the task is in progress, all callers with be waiting the same task instance.
/// If no task if currently running, a new one will be created.
actor SingleTaskProxy<T: Sendable> {
    init(_ taskClosure: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> T) {
        self.taskClosure = taskClosure
    }
    
    private var taskClosure: @Sendable () async throws -> T
    private var singleTask: Task<T, Error>?
    
    var value: T {
        get async throws {
            defer { singleTask = nil }
            
            if singleTask == nil {
                print("creating new task for type \(T.self)")
                singleTask = Task(operation: taskClosure)
            }
            
            return try await singleTask!.value
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
class FooManager<Foo: Sendable> {
    private let fooProxy: SingleTaskProxy<Foo>
    
    init(loadFoo: @Sendable @escaping () async throws -> Foo) {
        self.fooProxy = SingleTaskProxy(loadFoo)
    }
    
    func loadFoo() async throws -> Foo {
        try await fooProxy.value
    }
}
```